# Subversion - SVN - Como marcar um arquivo como sobrescirto

Tags: svn

Senhores, estou com a seguinte situação.

Tenho um ambiente de desenvolvimento. Nele rodo um script que versiona os fontes no meu repositorio através do contrab do linux. É um interface totalmente console e não posso utilizar internet ou baixar qualquer outro pacote, apenas o SVN client mesmo.

O problema que tenho:

Através da ferramenta de desenvolvimiento o usuario pode execluir/modificar/criar arquivos/diretorio que o script cuida disso sozinho. O problema é quando ele exclui um arquivo/diretorio e cria um no mesmo local com o mesmo nome. Ai fica com SVN Code de Til/Tilde(~). Isso porque os arquivos .svn são excluido no momento o que me impede a realização de commit. Queria saber se tem uma forma de resolver esse meu problema. Obrigado galera

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que li, ~ significa que um objeto de um tipo foi substituído por outro de outro tipo. Exemplo um arquivo que se chamava abcd foi substituído por um diretório chamado abcd. Para corrigir o problema o melhor a fazer é renomear o objeto que está dando problema, remover o objeto abcd do SVN com svn remove, dar um commit para remover o objeto, renomear o novo objeto de volta para abcd, dar um svn add para o objeto e fazer um novo commit. Então você terá uma sequência de commits, um em que o objeto existia, outro para remover o objeto e o último para adicionar o objeto no SVN novamente.

Comment: Então, sim é isso mesmo. Porém, não é necessário ser de tipos diferentes, basta ser diretório. Isso resolve parte de dentro de um projeto, tipo project/diretorio/arquivo_diretorio_sobrescrito. Mas tem casos que o usuario remove o diretorio do projeto inteiro e depois aplica por cima, sobre escrevendo o existente. Até fiz uma forma de deletar o que está no svn e fazer um novo import e um novo checkout, mas com isso perco o historico de versionamento. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda; Vou tentar implentar desta forma

Comment: @Rorschach, não entendo a razão de alguém remover o diretório do projeto inteiro e aplicar por cima, isso não é boa prática de versionamento. Qual a razão de ter a necessidade de proceder desta forma?

Comment: Então, o usuario da ferramenta não tem noção do versionamento. A ferramenta quem deveria fazer isso, porém, a ferramente tem um desempenho ruim, princialmente trabalhando com vários projetos e vários usuarios. As vezes o usuario faz um backup do projeto e quer voltar esse backup. Ai da esse erro. Queria uma forma de fazer um "replace" no mesmo modo que o TortoiseSVN

Comment: O problema não é a ferramenta, mas sim a falta de conhecimento de como usá-la da forma correta então. O melhor seria que todos da equipe soubessem como utilizar uma ferramenta de versionamento de maneira que o repositório mantivesse todo o histórico sempre. Sugiro que dê treinamento sobre o assunto para os desenvolvedores, pois ferramenta nenhuma pode fazer milagres por ser mal utilizada. Uso SVN assim como uma grande parte dos projetos código aberto também o utiliza, e não tenho nenhum problema com ela.

Comment: No mais, o TortoiseSVN nada mais é que uma interface de usuário para o cliente SVN, então ele tem nada de diferente e recursos a mais em termos de comandos comparando com o cliente de linha de comando